# sprintf_s crashes

Tags: c++, winapi

I am getting a crash while executing the following code ocassionally at sprintf_s. This code was working many years without any problems. When I gave the size  in strcat_s and sprintf_s as in the statements below, the crash is not appearing. What could be the reason for this?

strcat_s(sztmpCurrDate,**100**,sztmpCurrTime);
sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate,**100**,"%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds););

```
char sztmpCurrDate[100] = "";
char sztmpCurrTime[100] = "";
SYSTEMTIME curTime;
GetLocalTime(&curTime); 
GetLocalTime(&curTime); 
GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                                DATE_SHORTDATE,
                                &curTime,
                                NULL,
                                sztmpCurrDate,
                                100);

GetTimeFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
                          TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT,
                          &curTime,
                          "HH':'mm':'ss",
                          sztmpCurrTime,
                          100);

strcat_s(sztmpCurrDate," ");
strcat_s(sztmpCurrDate,sztmpCurrTime);
sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate,"%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Are you using the ..._s versions, as you code does not pass the size of the buffer as I would have expected.

Comment: There is a template-ized version of sprintf_s that works with fixed-size buffers.

Comment: sprintf_s has the _s suffix, which means that it's not secure... ;)

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation for `sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If copying occurs between strings that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Your code:

```
sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate,"%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds);
```

copies from the source to the destination `sztmpCurrDate`. Also, you haven't specified the size of the destination string, which is required by `sprintf_s` (I don't know how your code even compiled like that). Try:

```
sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate + strlen(sztmpCurrDate), 100-strlen(sztmpCurrDate),
          ":%0.3d",curTime.wMilliseconds);
```

A better approach, since you're using C++, is to use `std::string` and then you won't have to worry about this sort of C string manipulation error.

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong syntax!!!**

Second argument of sprintf_s is **length of your buffer** and in your case when program crashes **you provided pointer to C string (char *)**. This is absolutely syntax error.

The compiler probably issued a warning, but sadly has let this pass. This is because sprintf_s takes three arguments + variable number of arguments. In your wrong case you provided three arguments so the compiler was satisfied, but he treated your "format string" as "number of arguments" and sztmpCurrDate as "format string".

If you used any other function with fixed number of arguments and you provided less than needed this would be a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the incorrect version:

`sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate,"%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds);`

Instead it should be:

`int slen = strlen(sztmpCurrDate) + 1;`

`sprintf_s(sztmpCurrDate, slen, "%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds);`

Refer to this [sprintf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

The code worked correctly, the code is not correct.

```
sprintf(sztmpCurrDate,"%s:%0.3d",sztmpCurrDate,curTime.wMilliseconds);
```

Rewrite as

```
sprintf(&sztmpCurrDate[strlen(sztmpCurrDate)],"%0.3d",curTime.wMilliseconds);
```

And for home work tell us why .....